# Android - Expandable Listview with static children

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

In my application I have a Expandable ListView with 6 group items and each of them should show the same content as below:

[image: ListView with static child]

Therefore I created 2 layouts (one for the group items and one for the children).
Because of my static children I actually don't have any children values for my ExpandableListAdapter constructor.

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listDataChild = listChildData;
}
```

How can I achieve to have static children without adding any values to them.

Comment: By static value you mean they're data not change ? if you're using recyclerview just initialize value in ViewHolders.

Comment: The result data will change of course. I have 6 quiz topics (groups) and every children should show the achieved result.

Comment: So, in define Array in resource file which holds your header data. again define Arrays for each childeren data. here is a good sample https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: Ok but what shoul be my children data? In my case it is not necessary to add any string data for my children.

Comment: define them as strings and in case of numbers Parse them with some like this: Integer.parse(your_string_number);